# Что такое "стяжень"?

Tags: смысл, устаревшие-слова

В фильме "Белое солнце пустыни" звучит песня про Стеньку Разина "Из-за острова на ст**я**жень". Да, именно *ст**я**жень,* а не *стрежень!*

Что это за слово? Оно означает то же, что и стрежень, или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, "стяжень", "стряжень" - этот вариант упоминается во многих источниках. 
Судя по всему, это просто народный "волжский" вариант того же слова.

Во всяком случае так трактуют некоторые современные авторы.
При том, однако, что слова у Даля вроде бы нет.

Еще разово обнаружил в значении "оберег" (или заклинание?), но сомнительно.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!

Comment: Стрежень( обл. стряжень) от него - стержень - центральная и основная струя, силовой вектор проточной воды, стяжень - околострежневая двусторонняя зона проточной воды, стягивающая накопленную кинетическую энергию в стрежень, т.е. в линию, в стержень.Так что кто говорил" стяжень", кто " стрежень", кто "стряжень"- всё  это область сильной воды в проточной... Вот здесь интересно: 
http://physics-animations.com/rusboard/messages/59499.html

Comment: @Людмила *Вот здесь интересно* - простите, но тут со второй фразы ясно, что это досужий треп человека бесконечно далекого от инженерной проблематики. Что тут может быть интересного, кроме и без того понятного значения "областного" слова?